# How to fix "CMAKE NOT OK"

Tags: cmake, osrm

I've followed the instructions from the OSRM backend GitHub [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Windows-Compilation) and when I go to run the command `build-local.bat`, I get the following message "CMAKE NOT OK - downloading new CMake 3.9.2"

I've tried the x64 and x86 versions of cmake 3.15.0-rc2 and 3.14.5 that can be downloaded from their [website](https://cmake.org/download/).

When I run `build-local.dat` as per the project OSRM instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Windows-Compilation
), the output is as follows:

C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend>build-local.bat

```
APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH: master
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend\appveyor-build.bat ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PROJECT_DIR: C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
cmake:
cmake version 3.14.5

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
CMAKE NOT OK - downloading new CMake 3.9.2
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://cmake.org/files/v3.9/cmake-3.9.2-win32-x86. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ERROR C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend\appveyor-build.bat ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERRORLEVEL: 1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ DONE C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend\appveyor-build.bat ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ERROR C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend\build-local.bat ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERRORLEVEL: 1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ DONE C:\Users\Derek\Documents\osrm\osrm-backend\build-local.bat ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you installed the new version of cmake 3.15.0 and 3.14. But on the appveyor-build.bat it checks for CMake version 3.9.2 only.
You can go to appveyor-build.bat to edit `SET CMAKE_VERSION=3.15.0`